# Boost Log to File not working

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I can't figure out why this example code doesn't work right. My compiler says that the functions being called are not members of the declared namespace. This is the example code for Boost log so why doesn't it work? What do I need to do?

I've already defined `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK`, and I have all of the headers included, that should need to be included. Additionally boost was installed via `yum` from the fedora repos, according to yum, the boost version is `1.55.0`.

Example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file.cpp

## Errors

```
main.cpp:33:5: error: ‘add_file_log’ is not a member of ‘logging’
     logging::add_file_log(
     ^
main.cpp:34:10: error: ‘file_name’ is not a member of ‘keywords’
          keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",                                        /*< file name pattern >*/
          ^
main.cpp:35:10: error: ‘rotation_size’ is not a member of ‘keywords’
          keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,                                   /*< rotate files every 10 MiB... >*/
          ^
main.cpp:36:10: error: ‘time_based_rotation’ is not a member of ‘keywords’
          keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), /*< ...or at midnight >*/
          ^
main.cpp:36:49: error: ‘sinks::file’ has not been declared
          keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), /*< ...or at midnight >*/
```

## Code

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```

## Make invocation

```
g++ -c -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -o main.cpp.o main.cpp
```

Linker flags: `-lboost_program_options -lboost_log -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread`

Verbose Log: https://gist.github.com/HSchmale16/d4dd5656a47ce82c63b2

Comment: compiler/make invocation ?

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou Added the linker flags and the compiler command for the failed file.

Comment: strange. Can you show a debug/verbose output of gcc ? Maybe the include directories are not included ?

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou I just added a link to the verbose log. Though I already checked if the include directories are being included.

Comment: Which Boost version are you using?

Comment: @zmbq Boost Version 1.55.0 I'll add that to the question as well

Comment: @HSchmale Silly question but, have you installed boost-devel ?

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou Yes, I did. Before even posting I ran `yum install boost*` and when that failed I ran the same command as a reinstall. The build still failed.

Comment: @HSchmale Try executing $ ls /usr/include/boost. Do you get results back ?

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou Yes, log is in the directory

Comment: @HSchmale Try, --std=c++11 in your gcc invocation

Comment: @TasosVogiatzoglou Still fail with `-std=c++11`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76833/discussion-between-tasos-vogiatzoglou-and-hschmale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your header files for anything missing and also include -lboost_log_setup to your compiler/linker invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I can compile this with no errors, no changes to the code.  Check your boost::log source to be sure you have what you expect to have.  My guess is your boost files have been corrupted.  Trust that this error indicates the function isn't found where the compiler is looking.

Comment: I've checked for corruption, and that did not occur. I downloaded the boost headers directly from the fedora repos via `yum`, and I reinstalled all of boost and it still occurs

Comment: Try to see if the included code is actually what is intended to be included. You can run preprocessor on the code by passing -E instead of -c in the compiler command line and then see if the preprocessed output actually contains the referenced symbols.